# LiveReload + Compass error- Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: compass-sass, livereload

I have windows 7 and I've installed ruby, sass, compass, and LiveReload 0.9.2. When I make an update to my .scss files everything works fine until I try to import compass. I'm receiving this error.

Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable

I've created a project in compass and have LiveReload watching the same folder.

When I run compass from the command line to watch files it works perfectly. It seems like LiveReload isn't finding the appropriate file to import. I've tried modifying the 'config.rb' file but still received the same error.

Is this a bug with the LiveReload 0.9.2? Or am i just being a numbskull?

Answer (score 0):

Have you trying updating ?

Also, there are a few stuffs you need to be sure in order to compile compass.

Have you checked -> http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86203-sass-compass ?

Please, verify the above linked and let me know in which state are you.